# Need explanations - Destructor call - c++ - exceptions in constructor

Tags: c++, throw

I am sorry for this question that is clearly an understanding of a text.
I am learning c++ from the book " The c++ Programming Language".

In the part of the exceptions, Stroustrup explains at page 357 that destructor will be called only when constructor is complete **(pict 1)**

But on the previous page (356) it gives an example of a class & says that the destructor will be called even if it's throw . **(pict2)**

I am not really understanding what he wants to explain us in the page **356**, it's certainly a bad english understanding on my part.

Can someone help me about the aim of this example ?

*Picture 1 (p357)*
[image]

*Picture 2 (p356)*
[image]

Comment: That's not what the text says. The text says: *"The destructor will be called independently of whether the **function** is exited normally or exited because an exception is thrown."* This does not contradict the statement, that a destructor is only called for fully constructed subobjects, in case the c'tor throws.

Comment: I wonder how far from copyright violation this book reproduction is.

Comment: @Oliv Given it has _at least_ 357 pages, reproducing two of them for the purposes of education almost certainly falls under "_fair use_" (though I am not a layer; this is not legal advice; this message may self-destruct in 10 seconds).

Comment: Scrolling down the text in the image, I thought I was drunk for a second

Comment: @StoryTeller: I was astounded to discover, upon reaching the bottom, that I'm not

Answer (score 4):

By "the function", page 356 is referring to `use_file`, not the constructor. If the constructor throws because `fopen` failed and returned null, then the destructor (and hence `fclose`) won't be called. However, if the object is successfully constructed and then `use_file` throws an exception later on, the destructor of `f` will be called and will close the file.

This section is illustrating RAII* (Resource Acquisition is Initialization). As it says, RAII saves us from having to write the cleanup code in `use_file` if something goes wrong; the individual objects will clean up themselves through their destructors. In some other languages, when something needs to be cleaned up immediately, such as a file handle, its use should be wrapped in a try-finally block or a using/try/with block. C++ destructors are called when the object goes out of scope, removing the need for this.

---

*This can also be referred to as SBRM (Scope-Bound Resource Management).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that, in fact he means if something went wrong after the creation of "f", the destructor of f will be still call